# awk compare 2 columns in 2 unsorted files and return specific columns in 2nd file after match

Tags: python, awk, sed

I wish to compare col1 and col3 in file1 with col1 and col2 in file2. If there is a match, I want to print col1 and col3 of file1 and col5 and col6 of file2. file 1 has no header but file 2 has a header. I also want to keep the order based on ordering in file1

Example:

```
file1:   
1 3 6 
1 3 7
3 3 5
2 4 9
0 5 3

file2:
A B C D E F G
2 9 D 0 5 X 9
1 7 A 8 6 6 G
1 6 D 5 5 T 1
3 5 M 2 2 R 9
7 9 X 3 1 1 4

Expected result:
    1 6 5 T
    1 7 6 6
    3 5 2 R
    2 9 5 X
```

I tried this:

```
awk -F ' ' 'FNR=NR{arr[$1$3]++;next};arr[$1$2]{print $5,$6,arr[$1,$3];}' file1 file2
```

It only prints col5 and col6 of file2. How can I get the result. I want it in awk but any other language is still okay

Comment: You can't create a unique string by concatenating 2 strings since `a bc` -> `abc` and `ab c` -> `abc`, you need to provide some kind of separator between them. So, as a start, `arr[$1$3]` should be `arr[$1,$3]` or `arr[$1 FS $3]` or similar and do the same for the other array index you're currently creating by concatenation.

Comment: I see that now @EdMorton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR == NR {map[$1,$2] = $5 OFS $6; next}
($1,$3) in map {print $1, $3, map[$1,$3]}' file2 file1
```

```
1 6 5 T
1 7 6 6
3 5 2 R
2 9 5 X
```